# What is the difference between git rm and git restore?

Tags: git

Since both those commands are used to remove files from staging area, what is the difference between in them?

Comment: The thing that looks like a magnifying glass at the top of your browser window is a search field.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the documentation yields that `git rm` is used to remove a file from the working tree and from the git index ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm)), whereas `git restore` changes the files in the working tree back to match how they are in the restore source (usually the most recent commit) ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore)).

So, as the names suggest, `git rm` is to remove something and `git restore` is to restore how it used to be.

I'd recommend reading docs for questions like this.